# How do I increase the ABV of a batch of beer?

Tags: fiz

Some dude from the VSHA is offering to find me better employees but he wants a good beer with higher than normal ABV as payment.  How do I increase the ABV of beer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to increase the ABV of a brew**, however - certain brews have "High ABV" as a characteristic, visible from the brew screen after viewing a brew:

[image]

Brewing this beverage will result in a brew with a higher than average ABV.

Answer (score 1):

Some brews, such as Sigel's Hoptometrist imperial IPA, comes with the property of High ABV.  I used this brew to satisfy the event requirement.